# Q.allSettled executes before anything is pushed to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I'm trying to learn how to use promises with arrays and some async mongo queries. Here's the method that I currently have, but `Q.allSettled` executes before my mongo queries b/c nothing has been pushed to the array yet that `Q.allSettled` is looking at.

How can I modify this method so that all my async queries are executed before `Q.allSettled.spread` executes?

```
function buildCaseObject() {

        var returnPromise = Q.defer();
        var promises = [];
        var allObjects = [];

        var subjects = rdb.collection('subjects');
        var observations = rdb.collection('observation');

        // Loop through all subjects from current subject list
        subjects.find({'player._id': {$elemMatch: {root: '1.2.3.99.100.2', extension: {$in : subjectList}}}}).each(function(err, subject) {

          var def = Q.defer();
          promises.push(def);

          if (err) {
            def.reject(err);
          } else if (subject== null) {
            return def.resolve();
          }

          var caseObject = {};
          caseObject.subject= clone(subject);

          // Add observations to the subject
          observations.find({subjectId: subject._id}).toArray(function(err, allObs) {

            if (err) {
              def.reject(err);
            }

            caseObject.observations = clone(allObs);
            allObjects.push(caseObject);
            def.resolve();
          });

        });

        Q.allSettled(promises).then(function() {
          // GETTING IN HERE BEFORE GETTING INTO THE CALLBACK OF subjects.find.
          // THEREFORE THE ARRAY IS EMPTY
          console.log('in spread');
          console.log(allObjects.length);
          returnPromise.resolve(allObjects);
        }).fail(function(err) {
          returnPromise.reject(err);
        });

        return returnPromise.promise;
      }
```

Comment: You should promisify mongo, and then compose promises - find is async so allSettled runs on an empty array and returns immediately.

Comment: That's more or less what I pointed out in my question. I'm not sure how to do it, hence the question :p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises and also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Those 2 links are examples without arrays. I know how to do the simple things. I'm stuck on this particular question regarding arrays. Please re-read thoroughly.

Comment: How is this any different? You'd promisify `.toArray` and then chain promises instead of use deferreds.

Comment: Because it wouldn't even get that far. You'd have to promisify `subjects.find.each` first. I've tried that and my attempt failed. It still gets into Q.allSettled immediately.

Comment: You can't promisify each - you need to use .toArray instead and promisify that.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BenjaminGruenbaum. It made more sense after you pointed out to promisify toArray instead of .each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

`Q.allSettled` will only capture the promises that are in the array at the time it is called.
You will need to wait until you have populated the array, perhaps with a promise for the completion of the `each` call above.

The other is that `Q.defer()` returns a `{promise, resolve}` pair. You will need to add only the `promise` to the promises array.

```
promises.push(def.promise);
```

Comment: As stated by Benjamin in the comments, the problem is that there is no "completion" of the `each` call - its callback will be called multiple times asynchronously.

Comment: Ok so I ended up getting this working actually with using `.each` but it's probably not as elegant of a solution as using .toArray rather than each. I basically had to create another promise to call before calling `Q.allSettled`. Also pushing the promise to the array and not the pair was a key piece too.